# How do I use javascript to pull all webpages that link to a page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure how you can use javascript to search through the code of all .htm files in a folder A and display on a specific page 1 all the pages in that contain links to page 1.
I've come up with an alg for a javascritp code that I figured was simple and should work.

```
x = filename of current webpage Z;
for every .htm file i in folder A;
   for every <href> in file i;
       if href's filename = x;
           put into iframe of Z, a link to file i;
```

I am new to scripting so I haven't been able to use the libraries to its full xtent yet. Is there a way to delve through all .htm using javascript and search throguh the code for links?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Node.js or Javascript in the browser?  JavaScript in the browser is all client-side, and has no direct access to the .htm files in a folder.

This is something you would probably be better off using PHP (or other server-side language) for.

Comment: Oh you're right. I was going to use some form of ssjs so i'd figure node.js would be what i will be using. I believe jsp, php, etc. are options but I not dealing with a database (just a file system) so I figure it was unneccasry.

Comment: Using JSP, PHP, ASP, etc does not mean you must or should use a database; Far from it.  The ability to interface with a database is just one of many many other features those languages offer; database interaction is not their sole purpose.

Comment: Yea, PHP does have all I need. i'd figure I'd try javascript since it stuck with the existing framework already up. Too bad I had forgoetten js was orig client side.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in the **BROWSER** is a client side programming language. Unless you request for all the files via ajax then you need to use something that can be backend.

You can use something else like [node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs) or php. Node.js is javascript executed not in the browser and instead in the backend.

Comment: You're answer is contradicting itself. Javascript is client-side ... use node.js (that js stands for javascript). There are actually quite a few javascript server-side versions.

Comment: Both simshaun and I are referring to the backend node.js framework. I think you are misunderstanding the .js at the end of name.

Comment: And the .js in "node.js" is actually part of the name http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs

Comment: Not misunderstanding at all. The .js at the end of the name does refer to javascript, yes it is part of the actual name, doesn't change the fact it refers to javascript. Node.js is a server-side implementation of javascript, thus javascript is both a server-side and client-side language.

Comment: There! now I can sleep at nights.

Answer (score 0):

Typically javascript is client-side and running in the browser. In that context you can't easily get access to the files on the server. You would have to communicate with the server to get that information.

Server-side javascript does exist, but is not common. If you have access to an environment that can execute classic ASP on a Windows Server you can probably run javascript on the server quite easily.

Here is a short article on the subject of server-side javascript.

http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-javascript-will-be-as-common-as-php/